# Python list unable to hold encoded unicode symbol

Tags: python

After doing

```
symb = []
    for unicodeOfSymbol in myList:
        print unicodeOfSymbol.encode('UTF-8') # This prints out the symbol perfectly
        symb.append(unicodeOfSymbol.encode('UTF-8'))
```

I tried to print symb but i got this which i think is byte string?

```
<type 'list'>: ['\xf0\x9f\x98\x82', '\xe2\x9c\xa8', '\xe2\x99\xa5', '\xf0\x9f\x92\x96', '\xe2\x99\xa1']
```

How do i get the symbols to be printed out in the list as it is? I am using python2.7

Answer (score 2):

Just print each element of the list; printing the list as a single entity gives you the *representation* of the string, not the string itself. Compare

```
print(symb)
```

to

```
for x in symb:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
>>> print '[' + ', '.join(['\xf0\x9f\x98\x82', '\xe2\x9c\xa8', '\xe2\x99\xa5', '\xf0\x9f\x92\x96', '\xe2\x99\xa1']) + ']'
[, ✨, ♥, , ♡]
```